# How to persist collection of same class with ormlite in Android?

Tags: android, collections, ormlite

I have one class which has collection of itself as one of the instance variables. For example,

```
public class Temp
{
    Collection<Temp> list;
}
```

How do we save this type of relationship with ormlite?

The reason the class was designed so is the json response that we get is like

```
{
    "element" :
           {
           "key1" : "value1"
           "key2" : "value2"
           "children":
           [
               {
                   "key1" : "value1"
                   "key2" : "value2"        
               },
               {
                    "key1" : "value1"
                    "key2" : "value2"                
               }
            ]
         }
```

Comment: I think this is bad class design.

Comment: Even I think its a bad design. If we declare another class say Temp1 then class Temp and Temp1 will have mostly the same member variables except Temp having list of Temp1.

Comment: There no need to design another class for that or another class variable as `Collection<Temp> list;`. You can simply store all objects of class `Temp` into `List`.